# Sending empty sql Array into oracle procedure

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, jdbc, procedure

I'm trying to send sql.Array into procedure but somehow it gets empty inside of oracle procedure.

My java code that fill sql.Array with data and try to send it into procedure.

```
         oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) JdbcConnection.getInstance().createConnection();
            String [] name = new String[]{"20206643799002684001","20206643799002684001"};
            ArrayDescriptor arrDec = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("ARRAY_VARCHAR2",connection.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class));
            Array arr = new ARRAY(arrDec,connection.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class),name);
            OracleCallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call bss_acc.ACC_STATEMENT(?,?,?,?)}");
            callableStatement.setDate(1,date);
            callableStatement.setDate(2,dateL);
           ((OracleCallableStatement)callableStatement).setARRAY(3,arr);
            callableStatement.setString(4,this.branchId);
            callableStatement.execute();
```

And in procedure I put log in order to see what value I'm getting after executing of this procedure. And always I'm getting empty array element which shows up in this procedure.

```
procedure ACC_STATEMENT
(
i_begin_date date,
i_end_date date,
i_ids array_varchar2,
i_mfo varchar2
)
is
o_ext_acc varchar2(20);
o_beginRest number;
o_endRest number;
o_name varchar2(100);
o_rest number;
o_type varchar2(100);

begin

FOR i IN 1.. i_ids.count LOOP
o_ext_acc := i_ids(i);

-- test

RAISE_ERROR(20000, 'o_ext_acc -' ||o_ext_acc);
```

**And I see after executing this error with empty o_ext_acc to show up this message I redirect it into other procedure**

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000: 
> 20000:  o_ext_acc -
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:205)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1043)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3714)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4755)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1378)
>   at com.uzb.bank.demo.service.impl.GenerateIntoXmlImpl.accountStatement(GenerateIntoXmlImpl.java:414)
>   at com.uzb.bank.demo.controller.Controller.accountStatement(Controller.java:72)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
>   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
> ```

**UPD**
When I put debug mode in order to see what's going on with arr then I have noticed this data.Which means array dosn't take value from it and it show up question mark instead  of it.

[image]

**UPD**

I know that I'm using sql array and changed it into oracle.sql.Array and tried to create with following code but it again runs empty.

```
 oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) JdbcConnection.getInstance().createConnection();
            String [] name = new String[]{"20206643799002684001","20206643799002684001"};
            oracle.sql.ARRAY a = connection.createARRAY("ARRAY_VARCHAR2",name);
            CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call bss_acc.ACC_STATEMENT(?,?,?,?)}");
            callableStatement.setDate(1,date);
            callableStatement.setDate(2,dateL);
           ((OracleCallableStatement)callableStatement).setArray(3,a);
            callableStatement.setString(4,this.branchId);
            callableStatement.execute();
```

**UPD 3**

```
        oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection connection = (OracleConnection) JdbcConnection.getInstance().createConnection();
        String [] name = new String[]{"20206643799002684001","20206643799002684001"};
        oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = new ArrayDescriptor("ARRAY_VARCHAR2",connection);
        oracle.sql.ARRAY a = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor,connection,name);
        OracleCallableStatement callableStatement = (OracleCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall("{call bss_acc.ACC_STATEMENT(?,?,?,?)}");
        callableStatement.setDate(1,date);
        callableStatement.setDate(2,dateL);
        callableStatement.setARRAY(3,a);
        callableStatement.setString(4,this.branchId);
        callableStatement.execute();
```

**UPD 4**

After send empty oracle.sql.Array it gives error from my procedure and print part it shows up empty sql array element

> java.sql.SQLException:
>    ORA-20000:
>
> 20000:  o_ext_acc:/*empty sending array element here is empty. Here
>   should be element of sending array*/ORA-06512: на
>   "IBS.RAISE_ERROR", line 74 ORA-06512: на  "IBS.BSS_ACC", line 30
>   ORA-06512: на  line 1
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)

**UPD 5**

I modify it procedure

```
FOR i IN 1.. i_ids.count LOOP o_ext_acc := i_ids(i);

-- test

RAISE_ERROR(20000, 'date:' || i_begin_date || 'accountElement ' || o_ext_acc);
```

then I got following error where I can see date but there is  **empty o_ext_acc**

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-20000:  20000:  date:02.09.19accountElement

**The prolbem I can't catch sending oracle.jdbc.Array in procedure somehow it comes from jdbc into oracle procedure like empty array and elements is empty**

**I run this procedure from Oracle and it works fine without errors**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of search There was main problem is datumnArray was ???. This means oracld db and jdbc was not match with their characterset.After adding this code.

```
 String s1 = new String(account.get(0).getBytes(), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
                String [] name = new String[]{s1};
                //oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = new ArrayDescriptor("ARRAY_VARCHAR2",connection);
                oracle.sql.ARRAY a = connection.createARRAY("ARRAY_VARCHAR2", name);
```

[image]

and adding This lib into maven

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This worked for me. I think both of them play crucial way to solve the problem.At the begining of the was following picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `oracle.sql.ARRAY` and `oracleConnection.setARRAY()` rather than `java.sql.Array` and `javaConnection.setArray()`:

```java
Connection connection = JdbcConnection.getInstance().createConnection();
OracleConnection oconnection = (OracleConnection) connection.unwrap( oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class );

String [] name = new String[]{"20206643799002684001","20206643799002684001"};
ArrayDescriptor arrDec = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("ARRAY_VARCHAR2",oconnection);
ARRAY arr = new ARRAY(arrDec,oconnection,name);
/*
 * Or
 * ARRAY arr = oconnection.createARRAY("ARRAY_VARCHAR2", name);
 */
OracleCallableStatement callableStatement
  = (OracleCallableStatement) oconnection.prepareCall("{call bss_acc.ACC_STATEMENT(?,?,?,?)}");
callableStatement.setDate(1,date);
callableStatement.setDate(2,dateL);
callableStatement.setARRAY(3,arr);
callableStatement.setString(4,this.branchId);
callableStatement.execute();
```

See also: [My answer for "Inserting to Oracle Nested Table in Java
"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51144013/1509264)

Comment: Mister @MT0 thank you for your answer but I change it into oracle.sql.Array anyway it gives empty value.

Comment: @MaksimVasilovich `setARRAY( 3, arr )` not `setArray( 3, arr )`.

Comment: could you please take a look to UPD3 anyway it gives error

Comment: In pom xml using ojdbc6 version 11.2.0. Not error but it sends to procedure empty Array this is I'm calling error

Comment: @MaksimVasilovich "it gives error" is not constructive. What error? Where? Please give the full stack trace and highlight which line number relates to which line of your snippet.

Comment: Take a look upd 4 please @MT0

Comment: @MaksimVasilovich `ORA-20000` is the result of `raise_application_error( -20000, 'o_ext_acc:/empty sending array element here is empty. Here should be element of sending array' )` being called in the stored procedure from `IBS.RAISE_ERROR` on line 74 following `IBS.BSS_ACC` line 30. Please debug the stored procedure as it appears at first glance that the Java is working and the problem is at the Oracle end.