# Java EE + Oracle: how to use GTT(global temporary table) to avoid possible long(1000+) IN clause?

Tags: java, oracle, criteriaquery

I have a query for Oracle database, built with `CriteriaBuilder` of Hibernate. Now, it has a IN clause which already takes about 800+ params.

Team says this may surpass 1000 and hitting the hard upper limit of Oracle itself, which only allows 1000 param for an IN clause. We need to optimize that.

```sql
select ih from ItemHistory as ih 
    where ih.number=:param0
    and
    ih.companyId in (
        select c.id from Company as c 
        where (
                ( c.organizationId in (:param1) ) 
                or 
                ( c.organizationId like :param2 )
        ) and (
                c.organizationId in (:param3, :param4, :param5, :param6, :param7, :param8, :param9, :param10, ..... :param818)
        )
    )
order by ih.eventDate desc
```

So, two solutions I can think of:

1. The easy one, as now the list from `:param3` to `:param818` are below 1000, and in the future, we may hit 1000, we can separate the list if size > 1000, into another IN clause, so it becomes:

   c.organizationId in (:param3, :param4, :param5, :param6, :param7, :param8, :param9, :param10, ..... :param1002) or c.organizationId in (:param1003, ...)
2. Both the original code and solution 1 are not very efficient already. Although it can fetch 40K records in 25 seconds, we should use a GTT(Global Temporary Table), as per what I can find on AskTom or other sites, by professional DBAs. But I can only find SQL examples, not Java code.

What I can imagine is:

- `createNativeQuery("create global temporary table GTT_COMPANIES if not exist (companyId varchar(32)) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;");` and execute(Do we need index here?)
- `createNativeQuery("insert into GTT_COMPANIES (list)"); query.bind("1", query.getCompanyIds());` and execute(can we bind a list and insert it?)
- use CriteriaQuery to select from this table(but I doubt, as CriteriaQueryBuilder will require type safe meta model class to be generated beforehand, and here we don't have the entity; this is an ad-hoc table and no model entity is mapped to it)
- and, do we need to create GTT even the list size is < 1000? As often it is big, 700~800.

So, any suggestion? Someone got a working example of Hibernate CriteriaQuery + Oracle GTT?

The whole method is like this:

```java
    public List<ItemHistory> findByIdTypePermissionAndOrganizationIds(final Query<String> query, final ItemIdType idType) throws DataLookupException {
        String id = query.getObjectId();
        String type = idType.name();
        Set<String> companyIds = query.getCompanyIds();
        Set<String> allowedOrgIds = query.getAllowedOrganizationIds();
        Set<String> excludedOrgIds = query.getExcludedOrganizationIds();
        // if no orgs are allowed, we should return empty list
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(allowedOrgIds)) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<ItemHistory> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(ItemHistory.class);
            Subquery<String> subQueryCompanyIds = filterByPermissionAndOrgIdsInSubquery(query, builder, criteriaQuery);


            Subquery<String> subQueryCompanyIds = criteriaQuery.subquery(String.class);
            Root<Company> companies = subQueryCompanyIds.from(Company.class);
            companies.alias(COMPANY_ALIAS);
            Path<String> orgIdColumn = companies.get(Company_.organizationId);
            /* 1. get permission based restrictions */
            // select COMPANY_ID where (ORG_ID in ... or like ...) and (ORG_ID not in ... and not like ...)
            // actually query.getExcludedOrganizationIds() can also be very long list(1000+), but let's do it later
            Predicate permissionPredicate = getCompanyIdRangeByPermission(
                    builder, query.getAllowedOrganizationIds(), query.getExcludedOrganizationIds(), orgIdColumn
            );
            /* 2. get org id based restrictions, which was done on top of permission restrictions */
            // ... and where (ORG_ID in ... or like ...)
            // process companyIds with and without "*" by adding different predicates, like (xxx%, yyy%) vs in (xxx, yyy) 
            // here, query.getCompanyIds() could be very long, may be 1000+
            Predicate orgIdPredicate = groupByWildcardsAndCombine(builder, query.getCompanyIds(), orgIdColumn, false);
            /* 3. Join two predicates with AND, because originally filtering is done twice, 2nd is done on basis of 1st */
            Predicate subqueryWhere = CriteriaQueryUtils.joinWith(builder, true, permissionPredicate, orgIdPredicate);  // join predicates with AND
            subQueryCompanyIds.select(companies.get(Company_.id)); // id -> COMPANY_ID
            if (subqueryWhere != null) {
                subQueryCompanyIds.where(subqueryWhere);
            } else {
                LOGGER.warn("Cannot build subquery of org id and permission. " +
                                "Org ids: {}, allowed companies: {}, excluded companies: {}",
                        query.getCompanyIds(), query.getAllowedOrganizationIds(), query.getExcludedOrganizationIds());
            }
            Root<ItemHistory> itemHistory = criteriaQuery.from(ItemHistory.class);
            itemHistory.alias(ITEM_HISTORY_ALIAS);
            criteriaQuery.select(itemHistory)
                    .where(builder.and(
                            builder.equal(getColumnByIdType(itemHistory, idType), id),
                            builder.in(itemHistory.get(ItemHistory_.companyId)).value(subQueryCompanyIds)
                    ))
                    .orderBy(builder.desc(itemHistory.get(ItemHistory_.eventDate)));
            TypedQuery<ItemHistory> finalQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
            LOGGER.trace(LOG_MESSAGE_FINAL_QUERY, finalQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString());
            return finalQuery.setMaxResults(MAX_LIST_FETCH_SIZE).getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            LOGGER.info("No item history events found by permission and org ids with {}={}", type, id);
            throw new DataLookupException(ErrorCode.DATA_LOOKUP_NO_RESULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error when fetching item history events by permission and org ids with {}={}", type, id, e);
            throw new DataLookupException(ErrorCode.DATA_LOOKUP_ERROR,
                    "Error when fetching item history events by permission and org ids with " + type + "=" + id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: One option would be to pass the `IN` clause parameters via an [Java array/Oracle collection type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51144013/1509264) and then use the `MEMBER OF` collection operator rather than `IN`. However, you would need to work out how to do that with a criteria query.

Comment: Another method would be to convert it to a [list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4722220/1509264) as that is not limited to 1000 items.

Comment: How about 1000+ OR? I heard the limitation of any or/and is 65535