# How to implement a property in a Java class Country (implements SQLData) mappeable to nested table?

Tags: java, oracle

In an Oracle db there is a "COUNTRY" UDT which contains a nested table of a different "CITY" UDT (every country can have several cities).

How can I implement a "cities" property in a Java class "Country" (which implements SQLData interface) that could be mapped to "CITY" UDT?

Comment: There is an [SQLData example of passing an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54347047/1509264) and an [non-SQLData example of passing an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51144013/1509264); however, I've never tried passing an object containing an array using SQLData.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the second example can help me. I'm going to study it.