Getting Invalid Column Type :2000, when trying to registerOutParameter in JDBC
We are using OJDBC11-21.9.0 version and MyBatis 3.5.16.
A stored procedure, which we are calling via CallableStatement/MyBatis, is returning an oracle object (struct) as OUT parameter.
For eg,
PROCEDURE MyProcedure(                                                                                                                                                                                   
   x IN customtype1,
   y OUT customtype2
);

Now in our MyBatis mapper file,
<mapper namespace="MyNamespace">

<!-- PROCEDURE UPSERT FX Trade data -->
<insert id="mycall" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {CALL MyPackage.MyProcedure(
            #{x, mode=IN, jdbcType=JAVA_OBJECT, 
               typeHandler=com.learning.MyHandler1},
            #{y, mode=OUT, jdbcType=JAVA_OBJECT, 
               typeHandler=com.learning.MyHandler2}
    )}
</insert>
</mapper>

But this is throwing error , while calling org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.CallableStatementHandler.registerOutputParameters, which is internally calling oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getInternalType() and taking the argument as 2000, which represents JAVA_OBJECT.
When I looked into OracleStatement code using decomiler, I do not see getInternalType handling 2000 and hence returning
uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type: 2000]

I understand why this is coming, but don't understand why 2000 is not supported or what is the work around to handle a OUT parameter which is needs to be converted to a JAVA_OBJECT.
Any pointers here ?
Thanks

jdbcType should be STRUCT. This demo project contains  examples that may help.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51144013/1509264 gives a (lower-level) example of passing objects using JDBC - it uses structs on the Java side, as @ave said.

Thanks for the suggestion. The demo project really helped.
